# Formatting Factoring A Trinomial

Tags: formatting, tikz-arrows

I am trying to write this in a more sophisticated way. I am happy with this output but it was done by  trial and error. Perhaps I can use \tikzmark to clean this up? Any suggestions?

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz,xcolor,amsmath,colortbl}

 \begin{document}
 For example, since
 $$(2x+1)(x+6)=2x^{2}+13x+6,$$ 
 a factored form of $2x^{2}+13x+6$ is $(2x+1)(x+6)$.\\
 Notice that $2x$ and $x$ are factors of $2x^{2}$, the first term of the 
 trinomial. Also, $6$ and $1$ are factors of $6$, the last term of the 
 trinomial, as shown:
\[ \begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$\color{blue}{2x^{2}}\color{black}{}+13x+\color{red} 
{6}\color{black}{}=(2x+1)(x+6)$};
%%%%%TOP Arrows
\draw[blue,-] (-2.3,.2)--(-2.3,.5)--(.7,.5);
\draw[blue,->] (1.5,.5)--(1.6,0.5)--(1.6,0.2);
\node at (1.1,.5) {\color{blue}{\small $2x \cdot x$}}; 
\draw[blue,->] (0.5,.5)--(0.5,.2);
%%%%%%BOTTOM Arrows
\draw[blue,-] (-.4,-.2)--(-.4,-.5)--(1.3,-.5);
\draw[blue,->] (2.1,-.5)--(2.2,-0.5)--(2.2,-0.2);
\node at (1.7,-.5) {\color{red}{\small $1 \cdot 6$}}; 
\draw[blue,->] (1.15,-.5)--(1.15,-.2);
\end{tikzpicture} \]

Also notice that $13x$, the middle term, is the sum of the following 
products:
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.8pt}
\[ \begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$2x^{2}+13x+6=(\color{red}{2x}\color{black}{}+\color{blue} 
{1}\color{black}{})(\color{blue}{x}\color{black}{}+\color{red} 
     {6}\color{black}{})$};
     \node at (1.3,-1) {\begin{tabular}{rl}
     \cellcolor{cyan!25!white}&\cellcolor{cyan!25!white}\color{blue}{1x} \\
     \cellcolor{cyan!25!white}+&\cellcolor{cyan!25!white}\color{red}{12x} \\ 
   \hline
     \cellcolor{cyan!25!white}&\cellcolor{cyan!25!white}\color{black}{13x} 
   \\
   \end{tabular}};
   %%%%First Line(left to right)
   \draw[blue,-] (.5,-.2)--(1.3,-.9);
   %%%%Second line  
    \draw[blue,-] (1.2,-.2)--(1.3,-.5);
   %%%%Third line
    \draw[blue,-] (1.6,-.2)--(1.65,-.4);
    %%%%Fourth Line
    \draw[blue,-] (2.2,-.2)--(2,-.9);
    \node at (2.1,-1.45) [right] {\small $\color{blue}{\text{Middle 
   term}}$};    
    \end{tikzpicture} \]
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, tikzmark will certainly help. Are you also interested in solutions based on the brand new but not yet published version that has `\tikmarknode` in it?

Comment: Please also note that you may drop all those `\color{black}` statements if you used grouping or `\textcolor`. `\color` does not have a second argument.

Comment: Hi Marmot, I am interested. If I did it myself I would probably make the same mistake of a tikz node within a tikz node. Thanks

Comment: Yes TeXnician, I wrote this  program probably one year ago and learned that what I have is redundant or not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal based on the [new version of tikzmark](https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark), which is not yet on CTAN, so you need to download it. As you see, I am using `\tikzmarknode` to make elements of equations nodes and then use an overlay tikzpicture to make the annotations. The only somewhat subtle thing is that you cannot easily shade a background that way. I ended up restoring the node contents explicitly, and am wondering if there is a way that could be automatized. (I am actually very positive that there is, but do not have the time to work this out now.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,fit}

 \begin{document}
 For example, since
 \[(2x+1)(x+6)=2x^{2}+13x+6,\] 
 a factored form of $2x^{2}+13x+6$ is $(2x+1)(x+6)$.

 Notice that $2x$ and $x$ are factors of $2x^{2}$, the first term of the 
 trinomial. Also, $6$ and $1$ are factors of $6$, the last term of the 
 trinomial, as shown:\smallskip
\[ 
 \tikzmarknode{1}{\textcolor{blue}{2x^2}}+13x+
 \tikzmarknode{2}{\textcolor{red}{6}}=(2\tikzmarknode{3}{x}+\tikzmarknode{4}{1})
 (\tikzmarknode{5}{x}+\tikzmarknode{6}{6})
\]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[blue,->] (1.north) -- ++(0,7pt) coordinate (aux1) -| (1.north -| 5) node[pos=0.49,anchor=east,fill=white,inner sep=0.5pt,font=\small]{$2x\cdot x$};
\draw[blue,->] (aux1 -|3) -- (1.north -|3);
\draw[blue,->] ([yshift=-1pt]2.south) -- ++(0,-8pt) coordinate (aux2) -| ([yshift=-1pt]6.south) node[pos=0.48,anchor=east,fill=white,text=red,inner sep=0.5pt,font=\small]{$1\cdot 6$};
\draw[blue,->] (aux2 -|4) -- ([yshift=-1pt]6.south -|4);
\end{tikzpicture}

Also notice that $13x$, the middle term, is the sum of the following 
products:
\begin{align*} 2x^2+13x+6=(\tikzmarknode{B1}{\textcolor{red}{2x}}+
\tikzmarknode{B2}{\textcolor{blue}{1}})&
(\tikzmarknode{B3}{\textcolor{blue}{x}}+
\tikzmarknode{B4}{\textcolor{red}{6}})\\
&\tikzmarknode{B5}{\textcolor{blue}{1x}}\\
\tikzmarknode{B6}{+}\quad&\tikzmarknode{B7}{\textcolor{red}{12x}}\\
&\tikzmarknode{B8}{13x}\quad\text{\textcolor{blue}{middle term}}
\end{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[fill=cyan!20,fit=(B5)(B6)(B7)(B8)] (fit){};
\node[blue] at (B5) {$1x$}; 
\node at (B6) {$+$}; 
\node[red] at (B7) {$12x$};
\node[blue] at (B8) {$13x$};
\draw[thick] ([yshift=-3pt]B7.south -|fit.west) -- ([yshift=-3pt]B7.south -|fit.east);
\draw[blue] (B1) -- (B7) (B2) -- (B5.west) (B3) -- (B5.north) (B4) -- (B7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Marmot , I just need help downloading the tikzmark library.

Comment: @MathScholar The link is https://github.com/loopspace/tikzmark All you need to do is to download and compile the dtx file with pdflatex: `pdflatex tikzmark.dtx` twice.I would put it in a local directory, in which you compile your TeX file, at the moment. Later, when the library is on CTAN, you only need to update your TeX distribution and do no longer have to worry about it.

Comment: I don't see the .tex file I need to download. I located the file 'tikzmark' on my system but my editor is  not reading the usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}. Again I do not do this often

Comment: @MathScholar Do you have the *new* version of `tikzlibrarytikzmark.code.tex` in your path, e.g. in the directory in which you compile your TeX file? What error message do you get?

Comment: Everything is there, the new version but it is still not reading the library

Comment: @MathScholar This is really strange and does *not* happen on my system. Does temporarily renaming the old library solve the issue?

Comment: I took the file out of the latex files completely so only the new one is there , I downloaded the master file ran the .dtx program and then place all the files where they get read by my system or 'the path'

Comment: @MathScholar Could you please tell me which error message you get? Could you check in the log file which files get loaded?

Comment: The library is fixed. I guess the refreshed worked??? BUT the errors "No shape 1 is known" etc. So we fixed the tikzmarknode problem.

Comment: @MathScholar I just repeated the steps to be sure the library did not change. That is, I downloaded the files, extracted them in a separate directory, compiled the dtx, moved the above TeX file there and it compiles like a charm. The output is as above. My only hope is that someone else sees this and has an idea what might go wrong on your machine.

Comment: We are there. I had the package \usepackage{pgfplots} in my main program and it did not like it. Any thoughts on that ??? I have it now and running. Thanks Marmot and sorry about the back and forth

Comment: @MathScholar I have no idea. I just added pgfplots and there was no problem. But if you could add an example that has the problem, that would be *very* helpful for LoopSpace, the author of the package. Could you please do that?

Comment: Well I just added the package back and no problem so I don't understand either. Thanks for your help now I need to study the program you published. Thank you

Comment: Out of curiosity when do you think this package will be part of the update on a distribution?

Comment: @MathScholar No idea, would like to know myself. Maybe ask LoopSpace by asking under one of his answers, and tell me the outcome, please. ;-)